# NextAuth don't respect the expiry date from Azure AD B2C

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c, next-auth

In my SPA application I use NextAuth as the authentication solution. My authentication provider is Azure AD B2C.
The issue I have is that users' sessions are kept valid for a month even though I have configured it to be 1 day in AD B2C.

I have tried adding these two options for testing purpose:

```
  session: {
    maxAge: 120,
  },
  jwt: {
    maxAge: 120,
  },
```

But after the 2 minutes have passed, refreshing the page creates new tokens without showing the log in page.

How do I enforce NextAuth to follow the configuration the B2C is providing?

What I expect to happen is that the user gets redirected to the login page after X hours of inactivity.

```
import AzureADB2CProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad-b2c";
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    // Even adding this doesn't help invalidating the session
    // Seconds - How long until an idle session expires and is no longer valid.
  
    maxAge: 60, // 20 Seconds
  },
  providers: [
    AzureADB2CProvider({
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_NAME,
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      primaryUserFlow: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_PRIMARY_USER_FLOW,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: `offline_access openid`,
        },
      },
      profile: (profile) => {
        return {
          id: profile.oid,
          fName: profile.name,
          email: profile.emails?.length ? profile.emails[0] : null,
          myClaim: profile.extension_myClaim,
        };
      },
      checks: ["pkce"],
      client: {
        token_endpoint_auth_method: "none",
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin

      if (profile) {
        token.myClaim = profile.extension_myClaim;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.

      session.myClaim = token.myClaim;
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
    signOut: "/auth/signout",
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having a similar problem, I just added

```
  session: {
    maxAge: 1 * 60 * 60, // Time in seconds, similar to have you have configured it in the userFlow in Azure AD B2C
  },
  jwt: {
    maxAge: 1 * 60 * 60, // Time in seconds, similar to have you have configured it in the userFlow in Azure AD B2C
  },
```

Now my users gets logged out after 1 hour of inactivity